# How to replace variable struct in golang http.NewRequest POST with request body

Tags: go

I am new in golang and i am having problem when modify data struct with request body, in this code i want to modify var To based value from request body, how to do that?

body: `{"phone": "1989876787"}`

```
type Payload struct {
    MessagingProduct string   `json:"messaging_product"`
    To               string   `json:"to"`
}

func Send(c *gin.Context) {
    data := Payload{
        MessagingProduct: "sms",
        To: "", //modify this from req body
    }
    jsonStr, _ := json.Marshal(data)
    fmt.Println("req body", string(jsonStr))
}
```

Comment: if you remove `os.GetEnv()` and other not needed lines, your code might work in the playground. This helps people like me who want to help you. I think for the root of your question even a request is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using gin framework, You can use binding function.

```
type Payload struct {
    Phone string   `json:"phone"`
}

func Send(c *gin.Context) {
...
   var payload Payload
   if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&payload); err != nil {
       // handling error binding
   }
   data := Payload{
      MessagingProduct: "sms",
      To:  paylod.Phone,
   }
...
}
```

Comment: thanks, its worked with 
```type Payload struct {To string `json:"phone"`}``` and
```data := Payload{To:   payload.To,}```